# Ember - RESTAdapter calls only one url when using nested adapters

Tags: json, ember.js

I'm using Ember app kit for one of my projects and I have a question about how RESTAdapter works and why is it used only 1 url when I use nested routers.

I have "customer" model and use routers like this:

```
  this.resource('customers', function(){
    this.resource('customer', {path: '/:customer_id'});
  });

//using these urls
    http://myapp/index.html#/customers
    http://myapp/index.html#/customers/1
```

in this case only "/customers" url is called for both to get JSON data and as I guess it filters whole JSON by id = 1 after it gets whole customers JSON array from "/customers".

In another case if I use non-nested routers like this"

```
this.resource('customers');
this.resource('customer', {path: '/customers/:customer_id'});
```

"/customers"  JSON resource is retrieved for first router and "/customers/1"  for second one.

So my question is why is it happening like this? Is there any way to use nested routers while keeping and retrieving resources separately by id when needed?

Thanks.

Comment: You should not be nesting these resources.  You should use your second approach.  Nesting of resources implies a hierarchy, but I think in your case, one resource is "all customers" and the other is "customer X".  I don't understand your question "Is there any way to use nested routers while keeping and retrieving resources separately by id when needed?"  These are `resources`, not `routers`, BTW...  There is one `Router` for your app, which is configured by mapping `resource`s and `route`s...

Comment: Can you provide example of hierarchy? Thanks.

Comment: For example, a `customer` object may have multiple `order` objects as sub-resources.  The `customer` resource is in scope when you are in a `order` route, like `/customer/xyz/order/123`.